# CSV Input Skipping Columns Into the Wrong Field Name

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I have a transformation that has a CSV input. My csv file is all over the places and separated by both one tab and some with two tabs. I think this may be causing my data to skip to the next column under the wrong field name. It skipped "CtrAcct in LegacySys" and few others so the values are all null in my transformation now. Is there anyway to maybe strip a tab and just keep it consistent with one tab?

See below, some data are delimited by double tabs and some with one. Data looks just like this but i changed out information for privacy.

```
"   Cont.Account        CtrAcct in LegacySys    Contract account name   c/o name    House No.   PO Box  Street  Supplement  City    Postl Code"             
"   1234567890      1234567890  JOHN WILLIAM RHODEN     3722        LION BRIDGE BLVD        GULF BAY    32563-3445"             
"   1234567890      1234567890  JOHN PAUL DIAZ      555     GRAND PARK BLVD     MIAMI   32533-6328"             
"   1234567890      1234567890  JOHN A RODRIGUEZ        210     RICHARD BAYSHORE DR     P C BEACH   32407-2543"             
"   1234567890      1234567890  JOHN M YOUNG        12      BLUE LAGOON DR      PANAMA CITY BEACH   32408-5125"
```

[image: Pentaho CSV Input Parameters]

Comment: Please post your code, a sample of the input file, and your results so we can see where it is going wrong.

Comment: Please check this example. I think first you need to write shell script to remove extra delimiter , then use input file component.
https://www.allabouttechnologies.co.in/shell-script/remove-the-extra-delimiters-in-the-file-using-shell-script/